# Typescript 2 can't find custom definitions

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use some external js libraries from NPM with my typescript project, unfortunately these libraries don't have @types definitions provided so I've taken to writing my own. The definitions I've written work when I nest them in `./node_modules/@types/<library_name>/*.d.ts` but as soon as I move them to e.g. `./@types/<library_name>/*.d.ts` they don't get picked up by the compiler and I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./utils/eventEmitter.ts
(1,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'events'.
```

I'm using: TypeScript Version: 2.0.3 from npm

I've got the following project structure setup

```
@types/
-- events
---- index.d.ts
node_modules/
-- @types
-----react, react-dom etc
utils/
-- eventEmitter.js
tsconfig.json
```

In my tsconfig.json I have:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "typeRoots" : [
      "./@types"
    ],
    "types" : [
      "events",
      "ajax",
      "path",
      "keymirror"
    ]
  },
  "exclude" : [
    "node_modules",
    "@types"
  ]
}
```

in **eventEmitter.js** I have the following:

```
import * as events from "events";
```

Just to clarify the concrete events module JS is located at `./node_modules/events/index.js`

Comment: Also running into this same issue.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi, yes, it turns out it was a bug with typescript, I've posted the solution as an [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40045116/1494647)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem described by my question has been acknowledged as a bug in typescript (I'm using 2.0.3).

The solution is to add the following config to tsconfig.json:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
         "*": ["*", "./@types/*"]
     }
     ...
  }
}
```

as per: [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11383)

Answer (score 0):

Please use it this way:

```
import * as events from "./events";
```

When you use

```
 import * as events from "events";
```

typescript search for it in `node_modules`, you need to give him **relative path** with **./**

Comment: Hi, to clarify: events is an external module, so the javascript for this module is located at `node_modules/events/index.js`

Comment: Do you have installed typings for it?

Comment: There are no typings available for it, I've had to write my own

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your file definition file in the root dir of your project and tsc will find it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid this doesn't work and isn't a very extensible solution

Comment: This works for me. Not sure what you mean by extensible solution. This file is a custom type definition specific to your app and it belongs to the app source code. The node_modules dir won't be a part of your code in the source control system anyway. Why keep it there?

Comment: Hi, can you clarify what you mean by "keep your file definition file in the root dir of your project". It sounded like you wanted me to move my `./@types/events/index.d.ts` file to `./index.d.ts` I tried this and it didn't work for me

Comment: Just generate a new project with Angular-CLI and you'll see a file typings.d.ts in the src directory of the project.

You can also check the location of typings.d.ts in this project https://github.com/Farata/angular2typescript/tree/master/chapter10/auction/client/src

Comment: cheers, but afraid I'm suffering from the same error, typescript 2 compiler isn't looking for the definitions in that file, only ./node_modules/@types.